# Executing the same JSP holding the onclick event

Tags: jsp, onclick

I would like to execute ABC.jsp after the onclick event, here is the code

ABC.jsp

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%..........some jsp code%>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<%
   .........jsp code
%>

<input type = "button" value = "submit" onclick = "abc.jsp"/>

</body>
</head>

I want the jsp to execute after i click on submit butnothing happens when i click submit

</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting from this code?

Comment: I am not getting any error, the button is not working

Comment: Do you want to call the jsp only by the onclick or like pap's answer is also fine?

Comment: If there is a way then i would surely prefer onclick, pap's version does not seem to be working for me as i am indexing the jsp as ABC.jsp?page_number=3 or so but i end up up getting the default page every time ,do you want me to put down the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="abc.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```